# Passing command line argument to another file imported in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a python file (`html2text.py`) which gives the desired result when i pass command line argument to it i.e., in the following way:

```
python html2text.py file.txt
```

- where `file.txt` contains the source code of a web-site and the result is displayed on the console...

I want to use it in another file (let say `a.py`) and store the result (which was getting printed on the console) in a string.

For this I need to first import the file (`html2text.py`) in my file (`a.py`). Can anyone tell me how do I proceed further...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good way is to create some API in your `html2text.py`. For example:

```
# html2text.py

def parse(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    # do the stuff
    return output_string

def main():
    import sys
    print parse(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you will be able to use it in your `a.py`:

```
import html2text # main() will not run
import sys

output = html2text.parse(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is the reorganize a little your `html2text.py` file. Append the line like this to your file:

```
def main():
    message = sys.stdin.readlines()
    a = your_def(message)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Now you're sure, that when invoking the file from command line, everything will go fine. Moreover, if you have everything kept in functions and classes, you can now in your `a.py`

```
import html2text
```

and work on it already in `a.py`.